# Is it safe to use the SMTP credentials encryptor on https://smtpjs.com?

Tags: authentication, smtp, token, credentials

I'm using the smtpjs script to send emails using javascript. On the website there is a tool to get a secure token instead of leaving your login credentials in the code.

Is this tool safe to enter credentials into? Is there a way to create the secure token myself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was a long time ago, but some other people can need it.

By using SMTPjs you giving you credential to SMTPjs by using the secure token or not. They need the credential to send a email for you, so there is no way to create the token yourself.

A secure way to do it is by using a service that use OAuth (or creating your own server to send mail, of course).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know of any guides on how to set up your own smtp script/server?

Comment: You can create a node rest API, and use nodemailer on the server (This is pretty simple). This wil do everything on the server, without third party app. (This is basically what SMTPJs do)